# Tangent line Optimization Homework

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

Find the point on the line $6x + y = 9$ that is closest to the point $(2,7)$
Find $x$ and $y$.

This is what I have attempted so far, but my $6x$'s cancel out, which leaves me with $0$.  I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

$$y = -6x + 9$$
gradient $= -6$ at point $(2,7)$

gradient $= \frac{y_1 - y}{x_1 - x} = -6$

$y_1 = 7$

$x_1 = 2$

$\frac{7 - (-6x+9)}{2-x} = -6$

$7 + 6x - 9 = -6(2-x)$

$6x - 2 = -12 + 6x$

$6x = -10 + 6x$

$x = -10$?

I don't know What I am doing wrong.

Comment: It might help to review problems 1 - 3 at https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/ericskey/www/231material/hws19.pdf

Comment: I modified your math expressions to make them easier to read (mostly by wrapping the expressions in $\$$ signs).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Why is the solution of
$$\begin{align*}
6x+y&=9\\
-x+6y&=40
\end{align*}$$
the point you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The distance between points $P_1 = (x_1, y_1)$ and $P_2 = (x_2, y_2)$ in the plane is given by the Pythagorean theorem:
$$
d(P_1,P_2) = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}
$$

In your problem, $P_1 = (2, 7)$ and $P_2 = (x, y) = (x, 9 - 6x)$ for some real number $x$.  The distance between these two points depends on $x$:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sqrt{(x - 2)^2 + ((9 - 6x) - 7)^2} \\
     &= \sqrt{(x^2 - 4x + 4) + (4 - 24x + 36x^2)} \\
     &= \sqrt{37x^2 - 28x + 8}
\end{align}
$$
Can you find where the minimum occurs for $f$ by searching for a critical point?  Do you see how to find the other coordinate from there?

Comment: the minimum would be x=14/37?

Comment: okay so that is my x coordinate, so i substitute that in to the y equation to find my y coordinate?

Comment: Yup, got the answer, thank you